# How to remove quotes in the column value pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file with quotes in the column values. How to remove those quotes from the column value. for eg.

```
+--------+------+------+
|sample  |id    |status|
+--------+------+------+
|00000001|'1111'|'yes' |
|00000002|'1222'|'no'  |
|00000003|'1333'|'yes' |
+--------+------+------+
```

When i read it i should have DF like below without the single quote

```
+--------+------+------+
|sample  |id    |status|
+--------+------+------+
|00000001| 1111 | yes  |
|00000002| 1222 | no   |
|00000003| 1333 | yes  |
+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loading `csv` data, You can specify below options & Spark will automatically parses quotes.

Check below code.

```
spark. \
read. \
option("quote", "\'"). \
option("escape", "\'"). \
csv("<path to directory>")
```

Comment: Can we do that for a parquet file as well.?

Comment: "Copy Home 400 Mini + 19"" TV + Antenna Upgrade EasyBuy Kapsabet"  , But I want my output as Copy Home 400 Mini + 19" TV + Antenna Upgrade EasyBuy Kapsabet. How can I do that?